# Google OAuth Token Expires

Tags: php, oauth, google-plus-signin

I have this code which works fine the first time I log in, but if the page is left open and I don't log out of that session I get the following message and I have to restart my browser to get my page up again. How can I have the token automatically refresh?

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.'...`

This is the code

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/gplus-lib/vendor/autoload.php';

const CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET';
const REDIRECT_URI = 'REDIRECT_URI';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI);
$client->setScopes('email');

$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
   session_unset();
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $me = $plus->people->get('me');

  // Get User data
  $id = $me['id'];
  $name =  $me['displayName'];
  $email =  $me['emails'][0]['value'];
  $profile_image_url = $me['image']['url'];

} else {
  // get the login url   
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

?>
<div>
if (isset($authUrl)) {
    echo "<a class='login' href='" . $authUrl . "'><img src='gplus-lib/signin_button.png' height='50px'/></a>";
} else { ?>

<!-- Some HTML -->

<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can´t capture the error 'Google_Auth_Exception' and generate new Token ?

if your tests to make a call to Service and google with that token before login,  you can to know if this token is expired or not and generate new token if the call failed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the authorization code flow. While requesting the authCode you also have to request the **Offline_Access** claim.

With that claim you will get the refresh token along with the access token. That refresh token then can be used for getting a new token every time the access token expires.

So may be where you are requesting the auth_Code you have to ask for another scope that will provide you the refresh token.

And for testing you can use Postman app. That will give you some idea about what information is getting received as you ask for different scopes.